# Particles.js with Wordpress

Tags: json, wordpress, themes, particles.js

My particles.js won't load with my WorpdPress custom theme. 
The console throws this error: 
[image]

[image]

I found plugin for this Particles effect, but I don't know how to use it :D And, I'd like to implement my own. 
So, particles worked just fine, until I transformed my website into a WordPress theme... It's obviously problem with a JSON file....how can I go around this?

btw....it's on localhost....would it make difference when on a server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I managed to solve this problem. Not sure if it's THE solution, but what worked for me was: I had to put the JSON config inline, in a custom app.js file. Then it worked.

When the JSON config is in a separate file, WP has a problem loading it. It throws GET 404 not found. So....this worked for me...

I found the solution here: https://github.com/VincentGarreau/particles.js/issues/157

Comment: Thank you! I lose 30min on this one :-D

Comment: Glad it helped. :D

Answer (score 0):

what I did was include the json settings in a variable and place that code in the javascript file that you put this code

```js
particlesJS.load('particles-js', 'assets/particles.json', function() {
console.log('callback - particles.js config loaded');
});
```

But I did not use particlesJS.load, just particlesJS. So it would look something like this

```js
var config = {
  particles: {
    number: {
      value: 100
    },
    color: {
      value: "#d4d4d4"
    },
    shape: {
      type: "circle",
      stroke: {
        width: 0,
        color: "#d4d4d4"
      },
      polygon: {
        nb_sides: 5
      }
    },
    opacity: {
      value: 0.5,
      random: false,
      anim: {
        enable: false,
        speed: 1,
        opacity_min: 0.1,
        sync: false
      }
    },
    size: {
      value: 3,
      random: true,
      anim: {
        enable: false,
        speed: 40,
        size_min: 0.1,
        sync: false
      }
    },
    line_linked: {
      enable: true,
      distance: 150,
      color: "#d4d4d4",
      opacity: 0.4,
      width: 1
    },
    move: {
      enable: true,
      speed: 2,
      direction: "none",
      random: false,
      straight: false,
      out_mode: "out",
      attract: {
        enable: false,
        rotateX: 600,
        rotateY: 1200
      }
    }
  },
  retina_detect: true
}

particlesJS("your-id-or-class", config, function () {})
```